# Mockito como moquear una clase dentro de otra

Tags: java, mockito

Estoy tratando de realizar un test. Donde trato de mockear una clase en concreto.
Para que entendáis el escenario tenemos una clase Controlador, Servicio, Dao, y por último la clase en cuestión que trato de mockear.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Main.class }, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("api")
public class UnitTest {

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    private static final String API_URL = "http://test:6536/api/url"; 

    private static final String DATA_CONSTANT = "{\"nationality\":\"Camboya\"}";

    private static final Bean BEAN = BeanBuilder.getInstance().withId("").withData(DATA_CONSTANT).build();

    @Mock
    private HttpIntegrator httpIntegrator; //La clase que despues de surcar controlador, servicio y dao hace la llamada y quiero moquear

    @Autowired
    private ApiController controller; //La clase la cual quiero que coja del contexto de spring para asi poder alcanzar todas las clases que son inyectadas(tales como servicio, dao etc)


    @Test
    public void post_Ok() throws Exception {
    final HttpResponseBean httpResponse= HttpResponseBean.newInstance(HttpStatus.OK.ordinal(), "OK", BEAN.toString().getBytes());

    Mockito
        .doReturn(httpResponse)
        .when(this.httpIntegrator).postRequest(Matchers.any(String.class), Matchers.any(Map.class), Matchers.any(String.class));

    final ResponseEntity<Response> response = controller.post(DATA_CONSTANT);

    Mockito.verify(this.httpIntegrator).postRequest(API_URL, generateHttpRequestHeaders(), DATA_CONSTANT); //Excepcion
    }
}
```

Cargo el runner de SpringRunner para poder aprovechar las clases que inyecta en el contexto al iniciar la aplicación. Ya que no me interesa mockear todas las clases. Solamente trato de moquear HttpIntegrator. Pero claro para poder mockear necesito el runner de mockito, entonces he añadido la rule para poder añadirlo.

Mockeo HttpIntegrator y establezco el comportamiento que quiero cuando reciba la llamada. Debugeando ya me mosquea que poniendo un punto de parada en el método al que llamo de HttpIntegrator puedo realizar el debug(Digo que me mosquea por el hecho de que pensaba que los mocks no se podian debugear, pero es probable que me este equivocando).

El tema es que cuando realizo la comprobación de si ha realizado la llamada obtengo la siguiente excepción y eso es lo que de verdad me asegura que no funciona.

> Wanted but not invoked

¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal?
Gracias de antemano.

**UPDATE**

La respuesta que recibo no es la misma que aplico en doReturn(). Ya que he definido la respuesta del mock con el siguiente:

```
final HttpResponseBean httpResponse= HttpResponseBean.newInstance(HttpStatus.OK.ordinal(), "OK", BEAN.toString().getBytes());
```

Pero lo que me devuelve no corresponde a eso. Es similar, pero el BEAN.toString() que me devuelve el metodo mockeado es el que me devuelve como si hiciera la llamada sin haber establecido la respuesta que debe tener el mock. Entonces al matcher le he establecido una serie de matchers y el error que me devuelve es el siguiente:

```
Mockito.verify(this.httpIntegrator).postRequest(API_URL, Matchers.anyObject(), Matchers.anyString());
```

> invalid use of argument matchers 3 matchers expected 2 recorded

Estoy buscando actualmente la causa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al usar `@Mock` solo consigues crear una clase mock para `HttpIntegrator`, no la estás inyectando en el Dao (al usar @Autowired sobre `ApiController` estás delegando la inyección de dependecias en Spring)
Para solucionarlo, lo más fácil es que anotes HttpIntegrator con `@MockBean` en vez de con `@Mock`

`@MockBean` crea la clase de mock y además sustituye cualquier bean que haya sido definido en el contexto de Spring por tu clase de mock.

El error de "invalid use of argument matchers 3 matchers expected 2 recorded" se debe a que en la llamada a `verify` estás indicando dos `arguments matchers`, y una vez que has incluido uno, todos los parámetros deben serlo también. Es decir, `API_URL` no puede ir junto a los otros dos parámetros.
Prueba a cambiarlo por `Matchers.equalTo(API_URL)`

Comment: Ya no me aparece la excepción aplicando un @ MockBean en vez de un @ Mock . Una última cuestion. Las clases que son mocks y levnta mockito se pueden debugear poniendo un punto de parada en el ide??

Comment: Y luego la respuesta que recibo no es la misma que aplico en doReturn(), Ya que internamente el controller realiza cambios. Teniendo en cuenta que el controlador/servicio/dao realiza alguna serie de cambios sobre los campos (como en campo fechas, donde lo que yo le mando que me devuelva una hora se ve alterada por una de las clases superiores que coge la fecha actual). Puede deberse a que no mockea bien? un saludo

Comment: Añade este último comentario a la pregunta para responderlo

Comment: Ya esta el post ediado @pablo